# javascript running function within a concationed variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, concatenation

the title is bit confusing maybe! sorry about that

I'm have a `JSON` response from Tumblr API to get a blog's posts

```
   $.getJSON('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/' + blogURL + '.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=' + apiKey + '&limit=' + postsLimit + '&jsonp=?', function (data) {
                 /* Posts Loop */
           $.each(data.response.posts, function (i, post) {

               /* Basic Post Information */
               // Removed to save reading
               /* Photo Post Information */
               if (post.type == 'photo' && post.photos.length == 1) {
                   var postPhoto500 = post.photos[0].alt_sizes[1].url,
                       postPhotoCaption = post.caption;

                   var $photoPostWrap = '<div class="post-wrapper">\
                                            <div class="p-photo post-wrapper-400">\
                                                <a href="' + postPermalink + '">\<img src="' + postPhoto500 + '" alt="' + postPhotoCaption + '"/>\</a>\
                                             <div class="p-details">\
                                                <div class="caption">' + postPhotoCaption + '</div>\
                                                <ul class="p-tags hidden"></ul>\
                                             </div>\
                                          </div>';
                   $('#grid-posts-wrapper').append($photoPostWrap);
               } // PHOTO POST LOOP
           }) // POSTS LOOP
       });
```

the code above loops in a `data.response.posts` using jQuery `.each();` I have don't problem with that, `$photoPostWrap` is a variable holds the posts `div`s & details, here comes the problems I want to get the post tags for the current post/index `i` and add it to

```
<ul class="p-tags hidden"></ul>
```

I tried using .each() again in the above tags, a simple test

```
                   if (post.tags) { 
                       $.each(post.tags, function (i, tag) {
                           console.log(tag);
                       })
                   }
```

works fine, but I still need them to be in `.p-tags hidden` list

so currently I'm stuck with that, here's what I tried:

define a function as new variable, I have to pass the complete `JSON` object that function (problem)

a method for writing a text right here? just an idea

so how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

```
if (post.tags) { 
    $.each(post.tags, function (i, tag) {
        $('.p-tags.hidden').append(tag);
    });
}
```

Comment: this would work if I had one element/object, because that appends the tags only to the first element in the DOM

Comment: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kVxws/ as you can see the tags are appended to first `.p-tags` list

Comment: Well, I'm also stuck :P

Comment: Well I posted a fiddle, play with it you might figure it out!